# Grid Datatemplate using Star sizeing not producing uniform layout

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp

I have a `ListView` bound to a collection of objects that I want to present in a tabular fashion. I have created a `ListView.ItemTemplate`

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid BorderBrush="{StaticResource ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush}" BorderThickness="1,0,1,1" DataContext="{Binding Wpn}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1.25*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1.25*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Border BorderBrush="{StaticResource ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush}" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding WeaponName}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Margin="12,0,0,0"/>
                        </Border>
                        <Border BorderBrush="{StaticResource ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush}" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" Grid.Column="1">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding WeaponLock}" TextAlignment="Center" />
                        </Border>
                        <Border BorderBrush="{StaticResource ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush}" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" Grid.Column="2">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding WeaponAttack}" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                        <Border BorderBrush="{StaticResource ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush}" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" Grid.Column="3">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding WeaponDamage}" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                        <Border BorderBrush="{StaticResource ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush}" Grid.Column="4">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding WeaponArc, Converter={StaticResource EnumDisplayConv}}" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                        <TextBlock Text="test" Grid.Row="1"/>
                    </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

And a `ListView.ItemContainerStyle` to ensure each item stretches across the whole width of the `ListView`

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Based on the `ColumndDefinitions` all being star sized, I would expect to see a uniform looking table across each of the bound items (ie, all borders in vertical alignment), but instead am seeing what looks like auto sizing in the at least the first column, followed by star sizing in the remaining columns.

[image: Bad Column Alignments]

Can anyone point out where I am going wrong, or if there is a better method to get the desired tabular look?

Comment: Did you try setting min width to 0 n max width to infinite?

Comment: @JustinXL on what element?

Comment: On your ListViewItem style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer buried in [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/79f0c7b4-83ff-4d02-a44c-56c70b3fc726/uwpxaml-incorrect-grid-column-width-using-definitions?forum=wpdevelop). I needed to explicitly set the width of the `Grid` in the `DataTemplate`. I bound `Width` to the `ListView.ActualWidth` property using `ElementName` and `Path` syntax and the result came out as desired. Probably not ideal for repeated use templates, but it works in this instance.

Comment: While setting the grid width explicitely is solving the issue, it is not the only solution. It's enough when the grid is getting a defined width from parent even without setting the grid width itself.

Answer (score 1):

Don't give infinite space to the listview content, then it will respect its given space:

```
<ListView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
```

Otherwise it will always measure its children elements with infinite width constraint and consequently the grid will allow its children to claim infinite space and then it will start ignoring the star size when some children claim to much space while others don't need space at all.

---

**Debugging the layout**

As explained, the parent container needs to specify a restricted width, because for infinite width, the grid column star sizing will fail. There is an easy way to determine whether the current parents satisfy the requirement:

Create a custom control

```
public class RestrictiveWidthControl : ContentControl
{
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        // check constraint. If the constraint.Width is infinite, your parent layout is not ready for reliable grid sizing
        return base.MeasureOverride(constraint);
    }
}
```

And place it in the problematic XAML area:

On a grid, it can just be placed at the same level (same grid row/col) as the control to be analyzed

```
<local:RestrictiveWidthControl/>
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text="{Binding Text}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Margin="12,0,0,0"/>
</Border>
```

Generally, just wrap the analyzed control

```
<local:RestrictiveWidthControl>
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text="{Binding Text}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Margin="12,0,0,0"/>
    </Border>
</local:RestrictiveWidthControl>
```

Place a breakpoint in the `MeasureOverride` method and inspect the input `constraint`. If it is infinite, your Layout needs to be changed somewhere.

Comment: I added this adjustment but it didn't solve the issue, the output still looks as per the image in the question. I have marked as helpful though, as it did solve something else that was going on with the layout when resizing the window.

Comment: @Lindsay maybe you need to show some more XAML... if my solution doesn't work for you, then the reason is most probably some container around the Listview, but I can't know about it.